# How to tell if an image has loaded correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, loading

Is there a way to tell, after the fact, whether an image (placed with the `<img>` tag, not via JS) has loaded correctly into a page? I have a gallery of head shots, and occasionally the third-party image server ends up serving up a 404. I can change the server-side code to use an `onerror="showGenericHeadshot()"`, but I really want to avoid making changes to server-side code. Ultimately, I want to determine if an image is missing or broken and replace it with a generic "Image Not Found" graphic. Things I've tried:

1. `Image.prototype.onerror = showGenericHeadshot` -- doesn't work for `<img>` tags
2. `$('img[src*=thirdpartyserver.com]).error(showGenericHeadshot)` -- doesn't work in IE
3. `$('img[src*=thirdpartyserver.com]).css('backgroundImage','url(replacementimage.gif)')` -- works, but still doesn't get rid of the broken image icon in IE

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/92720/jquery-javascript-to-replace-broken-images

Comment: Thanks @danp. I actually saw that page earlier but dismissed it because it had mostly to do with loading images dynamically. However, @Devon's answer (not accepted) with a suggested modification in the comments by @Sugendran gave me what I was after. I would never have found it without that link, so thanks!

Comment: welcome! there's usually something in the SO archive if you poke around :) glad it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, I'm not able to accept either @TJ Crowder's nor @Praveen's excellent answers, though both do perform the desired image-replacement. @Praveen's answer would require a change to the HTML (in which case I should just hook into the `<img>` tag's own `error=""` event attribute. And judging by network activity, it look like if you try to create a new image using the url of an image that just 404ed in the same page, the request actually does get sent a second time. Part of the reason the image server is failing is, at least partly, our traffic; so I really have to do everything I can to keep requests down or the problem will only get worse..

The SO question referred to in @danp's comment to my question actually had the answer for me, though it was not the accepted answer there. I'm able to confirm that it works with IE 7 & 8, FF and webkit browsers. I'm doubtful it will work with older browsers, so I've got a `try/catch` in there to handle any exceptions. The worse case will be that no image-replacement happens, which is no different from what happens now without doing anything. The implementation I'm using is below:

```
$(function() {
    $('img[src*=images.3rdparty.com]').each(
        function() {
            try {
                if (!this.complete || (!$.browser.msie && (typeof this.naturalWidth == "undefined" || this.naturalWidth == 0))) {
                    this.src = 'http://myserver.com/images/no_photo.gif';
                }
            } catch(e) {}
        }
    );
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<img scr='someUrl' id="testImage" />

jQuery('#testImage').bind('load',function(){
         alert ('iamge loaded');
});
```

**to avoid race condition do as below**

```
<img _src="http://www.caregiving.org/intcaregiving/flags/UK.gif" />
// i have added an underscore character before src



jQuery('img').each(function(){
        var _elm=jQuery(this);
        _elm.bind('load',_imageLoaded).attr('src',_elm.attr('_src'))
    });

    function _imageLoaded()
    {
        alert('img loaded');
    }
```

Comment: Except if you do that, you create a race condition. Sometimes the load event will fire before you hook it. The only way to be certain is to create the image element, hook its `load` event, and *then* set its `src`.

Comment: @TJCrowder - Confirmed. There is a race condition. The code works locally if I place it high in the page and it doesn't work if I place it further down. Would it work if I, at DOMReady, replaced the image element with a new image element or would that result in, possibly, two requests going out?

Comment: Cool. Thanks. I definitely do not want to cause two requests. Traffic is one of the reasons the image server goes down and I don't want my fix to make things worse. I may just have to bite the bullet and change the server side code. I'll leave this up for another day and see what other answers I get. Thanks to everyone so far for their help!

Comment: @Andrew: Ignore all of my vague thoughts from my earlier comments on this answer (sorry, Praveen, we ended up using your answer for a discussion). I think I've [got it sussed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3780344/how-to-tell-if-an-image-has-loaded-correctly/3780930#3780930). I've deleted the earlier wild ideas. :-)

Comment: @Praveen: Not bad, although it does mean the images don't get loaded unless JavaScript is enabled. I don't know if that would be a problem for Andrew (it would for me). Also, they don't start loading until the page is otherwise complete (which could be good or bad, depending on what he wants). Separately: Rather than `_src`, I'd recommend `data-src` since although neither of them is valid HTML4, `data-src` is/will be valid HTML5.

Answer (score 1):

Would an alternate text be sufficient? If so you can use the alt attribute of the img tag.

Comment: its reasonable, if you have the image inside a defined block level element with width and height etc. Should have alt tags all set anyway! :)

Comment: It's unfortunately not sufficient. I'm trying to provide a way for the page to fail gracefully. And the images do all have alt text already.

Answer (score 1):

I think I've got it: When the DOM is loaded (or even on the `window.load` event — after all, you want to do this when all images are as complete as they're going to get), you can retroactively check that the images are okay by creating one new `img` element, hooking its `load` and `error` events, and then cycling through grabbing the `src` from each of your headshots. Something like the code below ([live example](http://jsfiddle.net/ekXWB/1/)). That code was just dashed off, it's not production quality — for instance, you'll probably want a timeout after which if you haven't received either `load` or `error`, you assume error. (You'll probably have to replace your checker image to handle that reliably.)

This technique assumes that reusing a `src` does **not** reload the image, which I think is a fairly reliable assumption (it is certainly an easily *testable* one) because this technique has been used for precaching images forever.

I've tested the below on Chrome, Firefox, and Opera for Linux as well as IE6 (yes, really) and IE8 for Windows. Worked a treat.

```
jQuery(function($) {
    var imgs, checker, index, start;

    // Obviously, adjust this selector to match just your headshots
    imgs = $('img');

    if (imgs.length > 0) {
        // Create the checker, hide it, and append it
        checker = $("<img>").hide().appendTo(document.body);

        // Hook it up
        checker.load(imageLoaded).error(imageFailed);

        // Start our loop
        index = 0;
        display("Verifying");
        start = now();
        verify();
    }

    function now() {
        return +new Date();
    }

    function verify() {
        if (!imgs || index >= imgs.length) {
            display("Done verifying, total time = " + (now() - start) + "ms");
            checker.remove();
            checker = undefined;
            return;
        }
        checker[0].src = imgs[index].src;
    }

    function imageLoaded() {
        display("Image " + index + " loaded successfully");
        ++index;
        verify();
    }

    function imageFailed() {
        display("Image " + index + " failed");
        ++index;
        verify();
    }

    function display(msg) {
        $("<p>" + now() + ": " + msg + "</p>").appendTo(document.body);
    }
});​
```

[Live example](http://jsfiddle.net/ekXWB/1/)